# Compare two cells from different worksheets using for loop and array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a list on cell A1 to lastrow on the worksheet "Input Here" and I have a complete list of string values on the "String List" worksheet on cell A1 to A692 which I have stored on the array `svr`. What I want to happen is the macro to check all values on column A on worksheet "Input Here" and compare it to the values inside array `svr`, one by one until it finds it match, and when it does, it will copy a range of cells from worksheet "String List" to worksheet "Input Here". I have tried the code below, and I think it needs more work.

```
Sub Main_SvrLst()

Dim inp As Worksheet
Dim lst As Worksheet
Dim svr(691) As String

Set inp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input Here")
Set lst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("String List")

lr = inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For svrctr = 0 To 691
    svr(svrctr) = lst.Range("A2").Offset(svrctr, 0).Value
Next svrctr

For a = 2 To lr
If inp.Cells(a, 1) = svr(a) Then

    Worksheets("String List").Activate
    lst.Range(Cells(a, 2), Cells(a, 8)).Copy
    inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Worksheets("Input Here").Activate

End If
Next a



End Sub
```

Comment: So when for example you have a match between `"Input Here"!A5` and `"String List"!A200` you want to copy the range `"String List"!B201:H201` to `"Input Here"!B5:H5`? Is that what you want? If not, can you please edit your question and give a concrete data example?

Comment: @trincot yes, that is exactly what I want to happen.

Comment: I see you already accepted an answer, but please consider doing this without code. Excel has functions for this out of the box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have changed some of your naming for clearer identification.

also off set your `Array`s to get the number referencing correct

```
 Sub Main_SvrLst()

      Dim inp As Worksheet
      Dim lst As Worksheet
      Dim svr(691) As String

      Set inp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input Here")
      Set lst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("String List")

      Dim LastRowOfInputHere As Long
      LastRowOfInputHere = inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

      Dim svrctr As Long
      'Made it 2 to 691 to off set your Header Row
      'This way the Array position and the row number are the same
      For svrctr = 2 To 691
           svr(svrctr) = lst.Cells(svrctr, "A").Value
      Next svrctr

      Dim InputHereRowReference As Long
      Dim StringListArrayReference As Long

      'With your original text it was comparing a two row offset between the "Input" and "String" Sheets
      For InputHereRowReference = 2 To LastRowOfInputHere

           For StringListArrayReference = 2 To 691

                If inp.Cells(InputHereRowReference, 1) = svr(StringListArrayReference) Then

                     lst.Activate
                     lst.Range(Cells(StringListArrayReference, 2), Cells(StringListArrayReference, 8)).Copy
                     inp.Activate
                     inp.Cells(InputHereRowReference, 2).PasteSpecial

                End If

           Next StringListArrayReference

      Next InputHereRowReference

 End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! I never tried using 2 for loops inside each other, but now I know that it can be used like that. Thank you so much! Marking as solved.

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked and that you learnt something. Remember to up vote the answer you find as being helpful and the answer you choose s correct

Comment: Hey @Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen, if lets say, after I have matched the details with the code above, and I modified column H of the `inp` worksheet, would there be a way for me to reflect or at least push that changes back on the `lst` worksheet?

Comment: I believe that would be possible but I think it would be over complicating it. I would rather just filter the "String List" sheet for that row using Colum A and then edit it there.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using VBA code, you could do this with formulas in your "Input Here" sheet:

In `B2`:

```
=""&IFERROR(INDEX('String List'!$A:$H, MATCH($A2, 'String List'!$A:$A, 0), COLUMN()), "")
```

Copy this formula to the right up to `H2`, and copy all that down as far as your input goes.

Comment: I noticed, for me, that it changed the font of the pasted text

Comment: Formulas don't change the font, the font -- as it is configured in "Input Here" -- is kept (the font is not copied from the other sheet). If you want it differently, just select the range B:H, choose the font you want, and it will stay.

Comment: That's why mentioned that it changed the font as formulas shouldn't affect font or formatting. Nice formula by the way

Comment: OK, I would not call that *"change the font"*, as really the VBA code changes the font, and the formula not. If you want to apply a certain format based on values, you can also do this without VBA, using the "Conditional Formatting" options (in the Home area on the ribbon). It is quite powerful.

Comment: Let me correct my statement. The font added to the cell via the formula is different to the font used on either sheet. Just for clarity

Comment: No, it is not like that. The formula does not *"add"* a font. The font that is already there remains untouched, while the VBA code through "Copy" sets the font, overriding the font-setting that was configured on sheet "Input Here".

Comment: There must be something else changing it. Anyway have a good day Sir

Comment: @trincot I appreciate your formula and I will take a look at this soon, as I am just beginning to unravel the many uses of excel, I will definitely look back into this formula. But as of right now, I can say I am more comfortable and familiar in solving excel problems using VBA. Appreciate the answer here.

Comment: I understand. One other argument to use in-cell formulas: VBA code changes the document, so the user will be prompted with "Do you want to save the changes?" even if they did not change anything manually. This will not happen with formulas. Also VBA code marks the document as "unsafe" the first time it is opened, so user must confirm the bar at the top (only once).

Comment: @trincot understand, and I appreciate the information you provided regarding the file being changed and what not. But now I have a new query that a simple formula such as the one you provided might be able to solve. I will edit my original post.

Comment: As you already accepted an answer, you should better ask this as a new question. Or are you considering changing the accepted answer?

Comment: @trincot I will ask this in a new question.

Comment: @trincot I have asked a new question, please check it on my profile.